# Run a cron job that performs other cron jobs schedules in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, cron

My system runs some intensive cron jobs twice daily.

These are lengthy scripts.

Occasionally, an action is performed in my system that requires the cron job to run on demand.

My idea is to create a master cron job that checks my database for a table of scheduled events and runs them as necessary.

Now, this all sounds too easy, so I ask: Is this a good idea? Are there any potential disadvantages or pitfalls?

Comment: suggestion - read up on cron assuming you're running on a *nix system and yes, this is in my mind the best way to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with the minimum cron-job interval, which is one minute, then your approach is good to go. I assume you're storing the `on-demand` jobs within one of your database's table, in which case you need to also consider the following:

1. you need to mark the `on-demand` jobs as `in progress` to avoid the scenarios where an `on-demand` job takes more than a minute and is also picked up by the next job
2. you might also consider retrying failed jobs, or jobs for which the processing script failed (either crashed or was killed by system for whatever reason)

If the `on-demand` actions need to be taken care of as soon as possible, and you also want to take care of the above two items, then you might consider a job scheduling approach, like using `RabbitMQ`. This approach has a bit more steep learning curve then the `cron`-based one, however the great advantage is that once you schedule the job you don't need to care much about it, except telling the `job scheduler` how to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned PHP, maybe you can just add cron jobs with it.
Regular shell commands can do the trick.

> Occasionally, an action is performed in my system that requires the
>   cron job to run on demand.

If you got access to `system()` or `exec()` functions in your PHP files you can add cron jobs and check for duplicates if necessary

```
(crontab -l ; echo "0 * * * * stuff") | sort - | uniq - | crontab -
```

this should add **stuff** to users crontab file and kinda check for uniqueness to avoid duplicates.